# I have created menu bar with translateX effects.Due to padding, I can not select the element which is coming behind to that menubar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am giving the css, html code of menu bar. Also I am attaching the screenshot which i have facing the problem.

Inspect Element of Menuabar:

[image]

Css -

```
.menubar {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

.menu {
    width: auto;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    transform: translateX(85%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(85%);
    -o-transform: translateX(85%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(85%);
    transition: all 1s ease;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

In Above screenshot, You can see that blue space, due to that, I can not click the link which is coming behind to that blue space.

Help me to make proper layout of that menubar so that I can click the links.

Comment: Post a minimal working code snippet reproducing the issue, or else we will be guessing saying _try this_ or _try that_

Answer (score 0):

Remove `transform` from the div class css menu:

```
.menu {
    width: auto;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: When i hover on that small div, it animates using transform property. & I want that hover effect.

`.menu:hover {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    -o-transform: translateX(0%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
}`